# state not updating after useEffect hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I need to get the `length` of the listing from `API` and display it as a counter.
But after loading, it goes back to original state.

```
let dataAll = []; //Global variable

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
const [isAll, setIsAll] = useState(dataAll);
const [state, setState] = useState({
    allCounter: 0,
    loading: true,
    });

const fetchAll = async (params = {}) => {
    try {
        dataAll = await TriggerRequestAPI.getAllTickets();
        const counter = dataAll.length;

        setIsLoading(false);
        setIsAll(dataAll);
        setState({
            state,
            loading: false,
            allCounter: counter,
            params
        });
    }
catch (err) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    console.log(err);
    message.error(`There is a problem in listing all table`, 3);
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetchAll();
    }, []);
```

Comment: Where are `setIsLoading` and `setIsAll` defined?

Comment: @Lucas-BetterCodingAcademy I updated my code

Comment: can u show console log your `state` before and after `useEffect` run?

Comment: @HảiBùi I console it. useEffect loaded first, it's 0 then inside the fetchAll function before setState, the count rendered 27 in the list then after setState, it goes back to 0